# JMeter - Set a dynamic variable for Loop Controller

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I have the following Setup:

```
| Thread Group
| -- BeanShell PreProcessor
| -- Loop Controller
```

In The BeanShell PreProcessor I have:

```
vars.put("myDynamicNumber", someDynamicallyGeneratedNumber+"");
```

In The Loop Controller I have:

```
Loop Count: ${myDynamicNumber}
```

I was under the impression this would work. Instead the Loop Controller cannot find the variable.  Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: It looks like I solved it by switching from BeanShell PreProcessor to BeanShell Sampler

Comment: ...As well it looks like any PreProcessor component should be added as CHILD to the control BEFORE which one you would like to execute processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Beanshell Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell), not Beanshell Pre-Processor.

I don't know why does JMeter allow putting Beanshell Pre-Processor at the same level as loop controller, it should go as a child of i.e. HTTP Request.

I'd also suggest to slightly change your code to be:

```
vars.put("myDynamicNumber", String.valueOf(someDynamicallyGeneratedNumber));
```

Which is more correct from Beanshell perspective.