# How to add dynamic loop count in loop controller in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

How to add dynamic loop count in loop controller jmeter using bean shell script ,
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423570/how-to-use-variable-in-jmeter-like-counter. you have asked the question already and answer is provided to you. If it is different from the question, then please share more details like what you tried, what you are getting and what is expecting? share screen shots for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter - Set a dynamic variable for Loop Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659274/jmeter-set-a-dynamic-variable-for-loop-controller)

Answer (score 0):

In the loop controller use:

- [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function like `${__V(somevariable)}`

  or
- [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function like `${__P(someproperty,)}`

for JMeter Variable or JMeter Property correspondingly.

In the Beanshell test elements you will be able to set the values like

```
vars.putObject("somevariable", "5");  // for JMeter Variable
props.putObject("somevariable", "5"); // for JMeter Property
```

where:

- `vars` is the instance of [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class which provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables in scope (scope is limited to current Thread Group only)
- `props` is normal [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) instance plus JMeter-specific properties originated from *jmeter.properties* or *user.properties* files or set via command-line arguments, etc. Properties are global for the whole Java Virtual Machine hence can be used to share data between different Thread Groups

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using scripting in JMeter tests.